# How To Create Javascript Array From Single HTML Input?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<input type="text" id="blah" value="'a1','a2'">
<script>
dd=document.getElementById('blah').value

cars = [dd]
console.log(cars)
</script>
```

When I try to do it in console I see the result:
['"a1", "a2"']
This is why I can't use it as array.
What I want is:
["a1","a2"]
I want to use it as array. How can I do it? Is it possible?

Comment: You need to `parse` this value string in to the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="blah" value="'a1','a2'">
<script>
dd=document.getElementById('blah').value

cars = dd.split(',').map(e=>e.substr(1, e.length-2));
console.log(cars)
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are really amazing. Worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your situation but based on your current problem you can do something like this.

```
<script>
   dd=document.getElementById('blah').value

   cars = dd.replace(/[']/g,"").split(",")
   console.log(cars)
</script>
```

Comment: The solution of Yurri worked perfectly. Thanks for taking your valuable time to answer my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Also an option with RegExp split:

```js
// Get value
const dd = document.getElementById('blah').value;
// Parse
const cars = dd.split(/'(\w+)'[,]*/).filter(e => e);
console.log(cars)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="blah" value="'a1','a2'">
```